# Monitor widget missing from Jupyter

Tags: pyspark, widget, jupyter, monitor

What code or configuration or steps to take to restore monitor widget to EMR Jupyter Notebook?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-spark-monitor.html
Found this:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=308132
(It is dated August 15, 2019)

`sc
Starting Spark application`

ID  YARN Application ID Kind    State   Spark UI    Driver log  Current session?
36  application_blahblahblahsomenumber  pyspark idle    Link    Link    ✔

SparkSession available as 'spark'.

But running normal program doesn't show expected monitoring
like number of partitions, seconds elapsed, etc.

It just runs silently with no clue but for the asterisk next to code
`In [*]`
 
What gives?

See the graphic in the section under:
"The following is an example of the Spark job monitoring widget. 
from the page"
On this page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-spark-monitor.html

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in latest EMR notebooks update.